# I can't update my store as before (update rxjs to v.6 & angularfire to v.5)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I got a lot of problems since I upgraded my rxjs & firebase to their latest version (6 & 5).

Problem #1.

My store didn't work anymore cause of the breaking change, distinctUntilChanged() is now red underline and said: "Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not attribuable on parameter of type 'UnaryFunction, Observable>'".

```
private store = this.subject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```

Problem #2.

I can not set my store with new data with the tap operator (previously do)

```
articles$: Observable<Article[]> = this.db.list(`articles/${this.uid}`).valueChanges()
    .pipe(tap(next => {
        this.store.set('meals', next);
    }));
```

My store look like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { pluck, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from './app-admin/services/auth.service';

export interface State {
  user: User,
  [key: string]: any
}

const state: State = {
  user: undefined,
  meals: undefined
};

export class Store {

  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<State>(state);
  private store = this.subject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  get value() {
    return this.subject.value;
  }

  select<T>(name: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.store.pluck(name);
  }

  set(name: string, state: any) {
    this.subject.next({ ...this.value, [name]: state });
  }

}
```

Edit:

Thanks to @RonY_Patel.
It's currently work with the command

```
npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

and

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

I got red underline on my `.do` but the app it working and doing what I want it to do !

Answer (score 1):

npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save

Try this.
It will work.